# How to clone github npm server on my domain name?

Tags: server, git, npm

I'm trying to clone this
https://github.com/gnuns/allorigins
on my own domain
/var/www/example.com/public_html/
The domain is configured correctly. but nothing change after writing these command lines vis SSH

```
git clone https://github.com/gnuns/AllOrigins
cd allorigins 
npm install
```

I can't find the proper steps for making my own server works like [allorigins.me](http://allorigins.me)

I want my server to handle GET requests to parse JSON format of any desired page.

I've made everything on the README.md, I just can't figure out how to make this working on my server. I've written all the lines, installed npm, tested it on port 80 and port 1458 as they stated but it is not working. I only get a list of files or 404 page.
Thank You.